# How to omit very long lines from `git grep`?

Tags: git, grep, vim-fugitive

I'm searching through my repository (with vim-fugitive's :Ggrep), I have different .js files - the minified ones and the regular ones.

I would like to omit from `git grep` the minified files (in other words - the very long lines that match the query). I looked into `git help grep` and googled but couldn't find anything. All ideas are welcomed.

Comment: Is piping git grep output an option?

Comment: Why do you store minified js in the repo?

Comment: @hek2mgl Sometimes you just get the code and have to deal with it ;-) If you know any solution to this except changing the structure, but purely solvable in vim, I'll be glad to have it

Comment: @valk I like [Benjamin Kotte's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38889886/171318)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't actually *omit* long lines as requested, but to avoid your terminal filling up when a very long line matches (e.g. minified javascript) you can configure git to page the output through `less` with the `-S` option (short for `--chop-long-lines`):

```
# For current repo only
git config --local core.pager "less -S"

# For all git repos
git config --global core.pager "less -S"
```

or equivalently add this to the relevant `.gitconfig` or `.git/config`

```
[core]
    pager = less -S
```

Answer (score 7):

for me, the best way was to create a file with name .gitattributes and this content:

`*.min.js binary
*.min.css binary`

Comment: That's a great way to achieve the goal *assuming* file naming is adequate.

Comment: @valk You can choose the name, isn't it? If you for whatever reason cannot change the name, have  a file like `foo.bar.js` which is a minified one, add `foo.bar.js` to gitattributes.

Answer (score 1):

grep is a command-line utility for searching plain-text data sets for lines matching a regular expression.
you can use a regular expression to limit the search.

For example,
You can use curly braces to control the number of occurrences. For example, this means 0 to 10:

```
/^[a-z]{0,10}$/
```

The options are:

```
{3} Exactly 3 occurrences;
{6,} At least 6 occurrences;
{2,5} 2 to 5 occurrences.
```

Answer (score 1):

Benni's solution is pretty decent.  Building on that, if you want a slightly more generic solution, use `git grep`to look for text files in the repo that have lines longer than, say, 1500 characters.  Then mark these files `binary`in the `.git/info/attributes`.  Here's a one-liner to do that:

```sh
git grep -lI '.\{1500\}' | sed 's/$/ binary/' >> .git/info/attributes
```

You can also record this in `.gitattributes`, of course, if you want to version this (and your team agrees to it).